# How to resize Image in C# WinRT/winmd?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've got simple question, but so far I've found no answer: how to resize jpeg image in C# WinRT/WinMD project and save it as new jpeg?

I'm developing Windows 8 Metro application for downloading daily image form certain site and displaying it on a Live Tile. The problem is the image must be smaller than 1024x1024 and smaller than 200kB, otherwise it won't show on the tile:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx

If I got larger image, how to resize it to be fit for the Live Tile? I'm thinking just about simple resize like width/2 and height/2 with keeping the aspect ration.

The specific requirement here is that the code must run as Windows Runtime Component, so WriteableBitmapEx library won't work here - it's only available for regular WinRT projects. There is even a branch for WriteableBitmapEx as winmd project, but it's far from ready.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Example of how to scale and crop taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/490b9c01-db4b-434f-8aff-d5c495e67e55):

```
async private void BitmapTransformTest()
{
    // hard coded image location
    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\fantasy-dragons-wallpaper.jpg";

    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
    if (file == null)
        return;

    // create a stream from the file and decode the image
    var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);


    // create a new stream and encoder for the new image
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(ras, decoder);

    // convert the entire bitmap to a 100px by 100px bitmap
    enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 100;
    enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 100;


    BitmapBounds bounds = new BitmapBounds();
    bounds.Height = 50;
    bounds.Width = 50;
    bounds.X = 50;
    bounds.Y = 50;
    enc.BitmapTransform.Bounds = bounds;

    // write out to the stream
    try
    {
        await enc.FlushAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.ToString();
    }

    // render the stream to the screen
    BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
    bImg.SetSource(ras);
    img.Source = bImg; // image element in xaml

}
```

Comment: do u think that it would be a very fast performance solution when the code is on mouse moved ? what do you think ? Is its performance better than WriteableBitmapEX ?

Comment: @Apoorv I have no idea

Answer (score 12):

More simpler code to re-size the image, not crop. The below code re-size the image as 80x80

```
using (var sourceStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);
    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight = 80, ScaledWidth = 80 };
    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
        transform,
        ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
        ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

    using (var destinationStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, destinationStream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, 80, 80, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());                        
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1dda3a15-d299-40e0-b668-ec690a683f6e)

Comment: Using this I get *very* poor image quality on the resulting tile... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you get poor image quality from this code, try `transform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant`

Answer (score 7):

So here is my solution I came with after lot of googling and trial/error coding:

The goal here was to find out, how to manipulate images in WinRT, specifically in [Background Tasks](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27411). Background Tasks are even more limited than just regular WinRT projects, because they must be of type [Windows Runtime Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441572.aspx). 99% of available libraries on NuGet targeting WinRT are targeting only the default WinRT projects, therefore they cannot be used in Windows Runtime Component projects.

At first I tried to use the [well-known WriteableBitmapEx library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) - porting the necessary code to my winmd project. There is even [branch of the WBE project targeting winmd](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94114), but it is unfinished. I made it compile after adding [ReadOnlyArray], [WriteOnlyArray] attributes to method parameters of type array and also after changing the project namespace to something not starting with "Windows" - winmd project limitation.

Even though I was able to use this library in my Background Task project it wasn't working, because, as I discovered, WriteableBitmap must be instantiated in UI thread and this is not possible as far as I know in Background Task.

In the meantime I have also found this [MSDN article about Image manipulation in WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.aspx). Most of samples there are only in the JavaScript section, so I had to convert it to C# first. I've also found this helpful [article on StackOverflow about image manipulation in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013799/winrt-image-handling).

```cs
internal static async Task LoadTileImageInternalAsync(string imagePath)
{
    string tileName = imagePath.GetHashedTileName();
    StorageFile origFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(imagePath);

    // open file for the new tile image file
    StorageFile tileFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(tileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (IRandomAccessStream tileStream = await tileFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        // get width and height from the original image
        IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await origFile.OpenReadAsync();
        ImageProperties properties = await origFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
        uint width = properties.Width;
        uint height = properties.Height;

        // get proper decoder for the input file - jpg/png/gif
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await GetProperDecoder(stream, imagePath);
        if (decoder == null) return; // should not happen
        // get byte array of actual decoded image
        PixelDataProvider data = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        byte[] bytes = data.DetachPixelData();

        // create encoder for saving the tile image
        BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
        // create class representing target jpeg quality - a bit obscure, but it works
        BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(TargetJpegQuality, PropertyType.Single);
        propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
        // create the target jpeg decoder
        BitmapEncoder be = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, tileStream, propertySet);
        be.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, width, height, 96.0, 96.0, bytes);

        // crop the image, if it's too big
        if (width > MaxImageWidth || height > MaxImageHeight)
        {
            BitmapBounds bounds = new BitmapBounds();
            if (width > MaxImageWidth)
            {
                bounds.Width = MaxImageWidth;
                bounds.X = (width - MaxImageWidth) / 2;
            }
            else bounds.Width = width;
            if (height > MaxImageHeight)
            {
                bounds.Height = MaxImageHeight;
                bounds.Y = (height - MaxImageHeight) / 2;
            }
            else bounds.Height = height;
            be.BitmapTransform.Bounds = bounds;
        }

        // save the target jpg to the file
        await be.FlushAsync();
    }
}

private static async Task<BitmapDecoder> GetProperDecoder(IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream, string imagePath)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(imagePath);
    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".jpg":
        case ".jpeg":
            return await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId, stream);
        case ".png":
            return await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.PngDecoderId, stream);
        case ".gif":
            return await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.GifDecoderId, stream);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this sample we open one file, decode it into byte array, and encode it back into new file with different size/format/quality.

The result is fully working image manipulation even in Windows Runtime Component Class and without WriteableBitmapEx library.

Comment: how fast is this.. i need a solution which i can implement on mousemove event ..so it has to crop whereever my pointer is..on the go...is it suitable of 2K images? i am using writeablebitmapex ..its slow

Comment: do you have a sample code for this ? It is asking for classes for TargetJpegQuality

Answer (score 2):

Here is even shorter version, without overhead of accessing pixel data.

```
using (var sourceFileStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
using (var destFileStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceFileStream);
    BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(destFileStream, decoder);
    enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = newWidth;
    enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = newHeight;
    await enc.FlushAsync();
    await destFileStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the last hour and half trying to figure this one out, I have a byte array that is a JPG and tried the answer given... I could not get it to work so I am putting up a new answer... Hopefully this will help someone else out... I am converting the JPG to 250/250 pixels

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])byteArray);
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }
            image.SetSource(stream);
        }
        image.DecodePixelHeight = 250;
        image.DecodePixelWidth = 250;

        return image;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want quality image then add 

**InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant in  BitmapTransform ,**
here is example

`
 public static async Task ResizeImage(Windows.Storage.StorageFile imgeTOBytes, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {

```
        using (var sourceStream = await imgeTOBytes.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);

            double widthRatio = (double)maxWidth / decoder.OrientedPixelWidth;
            double heightRatio = (double)maxHeight / decoder.OrientedPixelHeight;

            double scaleRatio = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            uint aspectHeight = (uint)Math.Floor((double)decoder.OrientedPixelHeight * scaleRatio);
            uint aspectWidth = (uint)Math.Floor((double)decoder.OrientedPixelWidth * scaleRatio);

            BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform() { InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant, ScaledHeight = aspectHeight, ScaledWidth = aspectWidth };
            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                transform,
                ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
                ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

            using (var destinationStream = await imgeTOBytes.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, destinationStream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, aspectWidth, aspectHeight, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }`
```

Comment: this code is working but it is not decreasing the size of that image.
so I found that we can create a thumbnail instead of resizing the image.
 https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-thumbnails-sample-17575959/view/SourceCode#content