# How to correctly resize/recompress image

Tags: c#, image-processing, compression, windows-store-apps, image-resizing

I have spent the last 10-12 hours trying to figure out how to correctly make a downloaded web image smaller in size and pixels in C# in a Windows Store app under development.

Whatever I do, I keep getting artifacts on the final images such as a "half picture", gray/same-colored areas and likewise. Like if the stream has not been flushed correctly although I believe to have done so (not done so in the code below since it works without it...)

This is my approach for retrieving the image - this part works, but is included here to make sure all info is here (see code below):

1. Get URL of image
2. Use HttpWebRequest to get response
3. Create stream to get response stream
4. Create empty StorageFile and open for writing
5. Copy the response stream to the storage file.
6. Close everything

From there, I need to do the following:

1. Determine the size (e.g. using BitmapDecoder)
2. If the width of the image is above a certain amount (e.g. 700 px), it must be resized.
3. No matter what, the files are always too big and need to be compressed further
4. The image need to be saved as a jpg with image quality set to a medium/semi-high setting

I have tried many things including messing pretty much around with BitmapEncoder/BitmapDecoder, but no matter what I am still getting half-processed images.

Can somebody please help me find the correct way to compress and resize images?

My code in the current state:

```
using (var response = await HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(internetUri).GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var imageFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
               CachedImagesFolderEndFolderPath, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        string fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", 
               Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()));

        var file = await imageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
               CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also post a code that half processes your image ?

Comment: So you've showed us the code that works. What about the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I am not expert at networking, but why not use Image class? It can be loaded both from stream and file and it can be used for resizing (=using Graphics class, drawImage)...and saved in desired formats.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It seems I did not get emails when there was replies :-( However, I have messed around with it a lot more now and I will UPDATE my post with the answer. 

Basic part is that I needed to get all of the settings correct and have closed the streams to the source and target files with images before I reopened the stream. So right now I am doing it in two steps, but hopefully I will optimize this ...

Comment: @StefanDK Answers should be posted as answers, not edited into the question.  I've posted your solution as an answer instead.

Comment: Thank you, @Servy - still new to posting here ... Thank you for accepting my reformat of the code to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution was provided by [StefanDK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007066/stefandk) in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21102623/3):

It seems that the problem with my former solution was that I did not properly close the streams and that I did not have the correct settings.

Basically the solution incorporates elements from these articles:

- [How to resize Image in C# WinRT/winmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349611/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-winrt-winmd)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481126/windows-store-app-resize-bitmapimage-c-sharp
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709942.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465076.aspx

From the main part of the code I make these calls for each image that needs downloading, resizing and compressing:

### Main code

Note that I am well aware of the "not best practice" in assigning a string value and then setting it again.  This is prototype code that has not been fine-tuned yet.

```
var img = await ArticleStorage.GetLocalImageAsync(src);
img = await ArticleStorage.ResizeAndCompressLocalImage(img);
```

### Source code of the methods in ArticleStorage

```
public const string CachedImagesFolderFullPath = "ms-appdata:///local/cache/";
public const string CachedImagesFolderEndFolderPath = "cache";
public const string OfflinePhotoImgPath = "ms-appx:///Assets/OfflinePhoto.png";
public const int MaximumColumnWidth = 700;

public static async Task<string> GetLocalImageAsync(string internetUri)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(internetUri))
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Show default image if local folder does not exist
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    if (localFolder == null)
    {
        return OfflinePhotoImgPath;
    }

    // Default to offline photo
    string src = OfflinePhotoImgPath;

    try
    {
        using (var response = await HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(internetUri)
                                                  .GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // New random filename (e.g. x53fjtje.jpg)
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()));

                var imageFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
                    CachedImagesFolderEndFolderPath, 
                    CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                var file = await imageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
                    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                // Copy bytes from stream to local file 
                // without changing any file information
                using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);

                    // Send back the local path to the image 
                    // (including 'ms-appdata:///local/cache/')
                    return string.Format(CachedImagesFolderFullPath + "{0}", 
                         fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Is implicitly handled with the setting 
        // of the initilized value of src
    }

    // If not succesfull, return the default offline image
    return src;
}

public static async Task<string> ResizeAndCompressLocalImage(string imgSrc)
{
    // Remove 'ms-appdata:///local/cache/' from the path ... 
    string sourcepathShort = imgSrc.Replace(
                                 CachedImagesFolderFullPath,
                                 string.Empty);

    // Get the cached images folder
    var folder = await ApplicationData.Current
                          .LocalFolder
                          .GetFolderAsync(
                               CachedImagesFolderEndFolderPath);

    // Get a new random name (e.g. '555jkdhr5.jpg')
    var targetPath = string.Format("{0}.jpg",
                          Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                              Path.GetRandomFileName()));

    // Retrieve source and create target file
    var sourceFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(sourcepathShort);
    var targetFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(targetPath);

    using (var sourceFileStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(
                   Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        using (var destFileStream = await targetFile.OpenAsync(
                   FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            // Prepare decoding of the source image
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(
                                              sourceFileStream);

            // Find out if image needs resizing
            double proportionWidth = (double)decoder.PixelWidth /
                                     LayoutDimensions.MaximumColumnWidth;

            double proportionImage = decoder.PixelHeight / 
                                     (double)decoder.PixelWidth;

            // Get the new sizes of the image whether it is the same or should be resized
            var newWidth = proportionWidth > 1 ? 
                           (uint)(MaximumColumnWidth) : 
                           decoder.PixelWidth;

            var newHeight = proportionWidth > 1 ? 
                            (uint)(MaximumColumnWidth * proportionImage) : 
                            decoder.PixelHeight;

            // Prepare set of properties for the bitmap
            BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();

            // Set ImageQuality
            BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(0.75, 
                                                    PropertyType.Single);
            propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

            //BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(
                                            destFileStream, decoder);
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
                                          BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, 
                                          destFileStream, propertySet);

            // Set the new dimensions
            enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = newHeight;
            enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = newWidth;

            // Get image data from the source image
            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

            // Copy in all pixel data from source to target
            enc.SetPixelData(
                decoder.BitmapPixelFormat,
                decoder.BitmapAlphaMode,
                decoder.PixelWidth, 
                decoder.PixelHeight, 
                decoder.DpiX, 
                decoder.DpiY, 
                pixelData.DetachPixelData()
                );

            // Make the encoder process the image
            await enc.FlushAsync();

            // Write everything to the filestream 
            await destFileStream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        // Delete the source file
        await sourceFile.DeleteAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

    // Return the new path 
    // including "ms-appdata:///local/cache/"
    return string.Format(CachedImagesFolderFullPath + "{0}", 
         targetPath);
}
```